# constants in z3 – segmentation fault in c++ api

Tags: c++, z3

The following c++ api code for z3 results in Segmentation fault: 11
(z3 version 4.4.0 running on Mac OS 10.10.2)

```
#include "../z3/include/z3++.h"

int main() {
  z3::context c;

  z3::sort A = z3::sort(c);
  z3::expr x = c.constant("x", A);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i dunno about z3 but if `c` gets a random value because it's not defined this could end up sorting who knows what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `z3::sort(c)` initializes A to a sort object that is associated with a context, but not an actual (lower-level) sort object. (See also the [C++ example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp) for how to construct commonly used sorts.)

I believe there's currently no convenient C++-style way of constructing uninterpreted sorts. For that purpose we need to go down to the C-API function [Z3_mk_uninterpreted_sort](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga736e88741af1c178cbebf94c49aa42de) (which can then be wrapped using `z3::sort(c, ...)`.)